# Is creating SharePoint sandbox field types possible?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sandbox, office365

I want to create custom field type for SharePoint Online. Therefore, AFAIK, it must be sandbox solution. Is there any possibility to create this? Or something that allows me to work on "single item level" on the list (not in edit form but on the list). Maybe some option in item menu or sth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to remember that SharePoint Sandbox Model doesn't offer custom FieldTypes.

There is a really good introduction for Sandboxed SharePoint Solutions on MSDN (http://goo.gl/uXGLo).

SPIs like

- ContentTypes
- SiteColumns
- Lists

could easily be created by using CAML (SharePoint XML-DSL) or by custom .NET Code

Answer (score 1):

Only fields that use a built-in SharePoint Foundation field type, or a custom field type that is previously installed in a farm solution, are possible. A custom field type cannot be deployed in a sandboxed solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

For XML support, see [Sandboxed Solution Considerations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231562.aspx):

> Sandboxed solutions support the following capabilities and elements:
>
> ...
>
> Content Types/Fields

For API support, see [SPFieldCollection.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms472869.aspx):

> Available in SharePoint Online

P.S. It is possible to deploy farm solutions to SharePoint Online in some circumstances. But it is so painful that it should be avoided unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Yes, but these fields are rather columns in "site columns" (or sth like that) and, AFAIK, they're defined in Elements.xml. I want to have my own code-behind file for field and it's editor. And according to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg615464.aspx "Only fields that use a built-in SharePoint Foundation field type, or a custom field type that is previously installed in a farm solution, are possible. A custom field type cannot be deployed in a sandboxed solution." I think that this painful deployment of farm solution to SP Online is worth custom fields possibilities :)

Comment: You are mixing two terms: field definition and field type definition. The former is supported in sandbox solutions as outlined in my answer. The latter won't be supported because field type definitions require a fldtype*.xml file to be deployed to the 14\TEMPLATE\XML directory. Your question seems to be asking about a field definition, while your comment seems to be asking about a field type definition. Which are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to create my own field type.

Comment: It is not possible based on your link to What Can Be Implemented in Sandboxed Solutions in SharePoint 2010: "A custom field type cannot be deployed in a sandboxed solution."

Comment: As I see, creating custom menus on items (ECB) and ASP.NET forms is also impossible. The most useful and powerful solutions are blocked :/

Comment: I've also found that just about anything of substance requires a farm solution. IMO, SharePoint Online is not suited for serious custom development.

Comment: Exactly. SP Online may be good in small companies for which standard SP functionality is sufficient. And SP Online doesn't display pdfs :P