# Is it possible to deploy a custom field type in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Is it possible to deploy a custom field type in Sharepoint Online.
I know that a custom field type cannot be deployed in a sandboxed solution. We in process to deploy a custom field type in sharepoint online.

Is that possible?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204305/is-creating-sharepoint-sandbox-fields-possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only fields that use a built-in SharePoint Foundation field type, or a custom field type that is previously installed in a farm solution, are possible. A custom field type cannot be deployed in a sandboxed solution.

so custom field type in sharepoint online is not possible

Comment: since Sharepoint online supports only sandboxed solutions..I got it now